# WordPress pagination for sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

How to make pagination in WordPress for `wp_list_pages` or any wordpress filters for page_list.

```
$args = array(
    'before'           => '<ul><li>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
    'after'            => '</li></ul>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'number',
    'separator'        => '</li><li>',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 0
);

return wp_list_pages($args);
```

I have this code. How to properly change it for pagination?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Most likely nothing. I do not even know where to begin. For the help would be grateful.

Comment: Any google research, anything? We are not here to do all the job, showing at least minimal effort put into solving issue before posting it is required on StackOverflow.

Comment: please see this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38698/paginated-html-sitemap, it will help you